# Cannot Find Module 'preproc' in Python/PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, text-classification

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://runawayhorse001.github.io/LearningApacheSpark/textmining.html

I have loaded my data into a PySpark DataFrame, however when I get to the preprocessing step, I receive the error, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preproc'" I can't find any information online about what to pip install in order to be able to use the preproc module.

!pip install preproc within a Jupyter notebook returns, "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement preproc (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for preproc"

python -m pip install preproc within cmd returns, "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement preproc (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for preproc"

How do I proceed finding the correct package to install?

Answer (score 0):

Emailed the tutorial creator and will post his response for anyone who needs help in the future.

"The preproc module is designed for the preprocessing functions, such as check_blanns, check_lang, remove_features etc. If you include those functions explicitly, you do not need to import the preproc module."

Answer (score 0):

The used functions are defined previously:
https://runawayhorse001.github.io/LearningApacheSpark/textmining.html#text-preprocessing

You can use them directly like *check_lang_udf = udf(check_lang, StringType())*.
Or alternatively, save these functions into a python file as *preproc.py*.